# Sklearn classifier for array of numbers

Tags: python, mongodb, scikit-learn

(I'm using Python and scikit-learn sklearn)
I have a dataset which has (a LOT of) objects in this format:

`{"word":"something", "data":[12, 24, 54, 65, 76, 87, 45, 65, 32, 12, 65, 13, 54, 76, 45, 72, 12, 11, 54, 23, 65]}`

I have several of these for each word, I made a sample dataset with a 100 words with 3000 inputs each.
I made it with a script that generates a hundred "seeds", and from each one of these, it generates the 3000 inputs by making each number of the `"data"` array a random variation with a maximum of ±15 (for simulating random variations of real life sensors).

From this dataset I saved ~297000 to a DB (Mongo DB) called "Words" to serve as a training set. And the other ~3000 to another DB (called "tests") for making tests.

**Now, the problem I have is that only 20 of the 3000 tests I made, give a prediction, with an accuracy score of 1.0. These results doesn't sound right for me, so I think I'm not doing the classifier the right way.**

I tried with DecisionTree and KNeighborsClassifier. I assume these two aren't the right classifiers for the type of data I want to use. Which classifier should I use? Examples?

***EDIT***

I'm pasting a piece of the database: (I have like 300000 of these, where the words repeat 1000 each) The names are "label" and "features" because some video on YouTube told me that they were called like that haha

```
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[152,179,848,12,499,408,405,377,228,222]}
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[157,170,843,17,502,411,402,373,236,219]}
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[156,177,844,22,503,413,398,380,236,227]}
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[157,172,847,22,504,416,401,379,238,222]}
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[157,177,846,15,499,417,397,376,238,221]}
{"label":"XpTrKrqjOC","features":[155,176,846,14,508,410,400,370,229,225]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[230,1,190,985,173,483,178,216,601,309]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[235,6,188,985,170,486,183,216,605,312]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[235,2,188,985,171,478,175,216,600,314]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[234,-4,190,987,177,478,177,220,600,309]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[235,-1,191,983,172,478,180,219,598,306]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[234,-1,190,983,178,480,174,221,597,313]}
{"label":"cOYHgaxByT","features":[225,-4,195,990,170,479,181,221,602,307]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[546,73,52,445,193,175,158,561,317,503]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[551,69,52,440,198,172,154,566,312,504]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[543,77,55,445,193,179,163,565,313,508]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[550,72,56,443,193,180,161,563,319,502]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[542,77,55,450,194,173,155,558,315,501]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[543,72,57,450,191,176,156,560,318,508]}
{"label":"ZWmNqLVaIZ","features":[550,68,49,443,194,180,154,563,312,500]}
```

Comment: Your process in not entirely clear to me (what is X, what is Y; i assume "word" + "data" is X=input and "something" is Y=output). Try to be more precise. More formal. Is every sample randomly created with different statistics *per word* (=there is a correlation between X and Y)? If not, then nobody can predict anything, because every output is just random.

Comment: @sascha The real data will be obtained from a set of sensors, that will give values from 0 to 100. So I make a reading from the sensors and manually assign a word to the data, this will be for making the training database. So, then I input an array of numbers (new reading from the sensors) and I want to get a prediction of which "word" is. I'm really new at machine learning, sorry!

Comment: I don't care about the real data, if you are using synthetic ones. If my assumptions about input and output are correct and you use the same random-distribution regardless of the input, then no learner at all can predict something (and your scores are random-hits)! Just do your score-evaluation with random-guessing and compare the values. Just describe more precise what you are doing. If the random-variation is a normal-dist on the seeds and the seeds are randomly chosen, regardless of input, my statement still applies.

Comment: Okay, I'm really lost now... Maybe because of my bad english, but I think that now I understood. I will edit my post, please, check it and tell me if it clears up for you. Thank you a lot for putting so much effort on understanding me!

Answer (score 0):

I think [MultinomialNB](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.naive_bayes.MultinomialNB.html) should work pretty well if you first process the data using [LabelEncoder](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html) to get a sparse matrix with examples being rows and words being columns.

Comment: I made a test, but It gives me 1.0 accuracy score!! Can this be possible?

Comment: The process of your data-generation which you use to train is still not precise. It's hard to help if this important part of the problem is omitted. The shown part of your data looks like, all samples of 'XpTrKrqjOC' has feature 0 ~100, 'cOYHgaxByT' ~200, 'ZWmNqLVaIZ' ~500. If this applies to the rest, you will only need feature 0 and super simple classifier to get perfect score. So it still looks like your problem is in the data-preparation.